# Appium - xpath or locators to use variable input values - bluetooth selection

Tags: python, xpath, bluetooth-lowenergy, appium, element

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob5Wt.png)

Am trying to come up with testing mobile application on appium using python scripts.

Would like to take bluetooth MAC ID as input value in the python script and connect it using appium.

driver_find element by xpath by text works but prefer to take the selection as input value.

Any suggestions

ble = str("BTDEV_AB20")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//android.widget.TextView[contains(text(),'" + ble + "')]').click()

Find By Selector
id  app.com.bt:id/dev_name1
xpath   /hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.RelativeLayout/androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.widget.TextView[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob5Wt.png)

Attribute   Value
elementId
index   0
package app.com.bt
class   android.widget.TextView
text    BTDEV_AB20
resource-id app.com.bt:id/dev_name1
checkable   False
checked False
clickable   false
enabled true
focusable   false
focused false
long-clickable  false
password    false
scrollable  false
selected    false
bounds  [98,215][255,252]
displayed   true

Comment: Please rephrase your question, using correct punctuation, quoting, code samples and error messages you receive. The way it currently is, your question is practically incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

Did some research and solved by following

```
By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='"+ble+"']");
```